# Problem with reactive variables and change tracking in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, vue.js

I am trying to select message from `json` file after what `click event` is raised. My problem is, when I first click on the message from `list`, it did not select anything (or it seems to me). If I click for the second time, the selected messages are two of them (and duplicates, of course) and so on....

I know where the problem probably is:

```
import SelectedItem from "../Interfaces/SelectedItem";

const selectedMessage = ref<MessageInterface | null>(null);

const selectMessage = (message: any) => {
  selectedMessage.value = message;
  SelectedItem(selectedMessage); 
};
```

The SelectedItem modul looks like this:

```
 import { watch, Ref } from "vue";

export default function SelectedItem<Type>(selectedValue: Ref<Type>): Type {
  watch(selectedValue, (newVal) => {
    chooseItem(newVal);
  });

  function chooseItem(item: Type) {
    if (item) {
      selectedValue.value = item;
      console.log(selectedValue.value);
    }
  }

  return selectedValue.value; 
}
```

The reason, why `SelectedItem` function is separated is, I am using the same logic and code  in more than one file, so do not want to repeat.

Here:

```
<template>
<div>
  <select v-model="selectedMessage">
    <option value="">Vyberte cílové číslo</option>
    <option
      v-for="(message, index) in SMSMessages"
      :key="index"
      :value="message.targetNumber"
    >
      {{ message.targetNumber }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <p>Vybráno: {{ selectedMessage }}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import SMSMessages from "../data/sms-messages.json";
import { ref } from "vue";
import SelectedItem from '../Interfaces/SelectedItem'
const selectedMessage = ref<string>("");

selectedMessage.value = SelectedItem(selectedMessage);
</script>
```

Full code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="(message, index) in SMSMessages"
        :key="index"
        @click="selectMessage(message)"
      >
        <p>Body: {{ message.body }}</p>
        <p>Origin Number: {{ message.originNumber }}</p>
        <p>Target Number: {{ message.targetNumber }}</p>
        <p>Direction: {{ message.direction }}</p>
        <p>Message Date: {{ message.messageDt }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import SMSMessages from "../data/sms-messages.json";
import MessageInterface from "../Interfaces/MessageInterface";
import { ref } from "vue";
import SelectedItem from "../Interfaces/SelectedItem";

const selectedMessage = ref<MessageInterface | null>(null);

const selectMessage = (message: any) => {
  selectedMessage.value = message;
  SelectedItem(selectedMessage); 
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Watchers that aren't [eager watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#eager-watchers) will only run when the watched value is changed, not on initialization. This is why you don't see output the first time.
- Every time you call `SelectedItem()`, you set a new watcher. This is why you see multiple outputs later on.

Note that the watcher is triggered when `selectedMessage.value` is assigned a new value, and the new value is put into the watch's handler as first parameter. Assigning it again to `selectedMessage.value` sets the same value, basically doing nothing (i.e. `selectedMessage.value = selectedMessage.value`). The way it is, you could just remove `SelectedItem()` completely and it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to keep `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Should be easy to fix, you just have to turn the watcher into an eager watcher and make sure SelectedItem() runs only once. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I took it to mean that to solve my problem, I had to get rid of `SelectedItem`

Comment: Did you figure it out? If the answer helped you, consider leaving and upvote or marking it as the accepted answer.